# Sum positive and negative values grouped by other values

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

Using this data:

```
 Respon    Type     Value
   Mark     -1        2
   Mark     -2        4
   Sheyla    1        10
   Ana       1        4
   Sheyla    2        3
   Mark      1        4
   Ana      -2        6
   Ana       2        7
```

I would like to get two columns named "positive" and "negative" which sums positive and negative values depending on type and grouped by Respon

```
Respon    Positive     Negative
 Mark         4           6
 Sheyla       13          0
 Ana          11          6
```

Comment: in base R: `reshape(aggregate(Value ~ Respon + sign(Type), df, FUN="sum"), idvar="Respon", timevar="sign(Type)", direction = "wide")`

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Respon)  %>% 
    summarise(Positive = sum(Value[Type>0]), Negative = sum(Value[Type <0]))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#  Respon Positive Negative
#   <chr>    <int>    <int>
#1    Ana       11        6
#2   Mark        4        6
#3 Sheyla       13        0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Respon ~ sign(Type), value.var = "Value", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R `xtabs` we can group `Value` on `Respon` and signed `Type` variable.

```
xtabs(Value~Respon + sign(Type), df)

#       sign(Type)
#  Respon   -1  1
#  Ana       6 11
#  Mark      6  4
#  Sheyla    0 13
```